# Regex Find any combination of \d and [ -] as long as there is at least K \d together and no more than 10

Tags: regex

Hey all given the examples

> 1234567890
>
> 12 3456789 0
>
> 123 456-7890
>
> 12345 678 90
>
> 123-4-5-6789 0

total digits are fixed, and any grouping larger than some arbitrary k (min_group_length) are allowed, with max groups being set (optional but preferred)

I need to identify these in Regex, my current solution is disgusting.
I first find the partitions of 10, then the permutations of them, then convert all that to regex, resulting in hundreds of groupings

```
            printAllUniqueParts(10);
            int min_groups = 1;
            int min_group_len = 2;
            res.RemoveAll(s => s.Split(' ').ToList().Intersect(Enumerable.Range(0, min_group_len).Select(n => n.ToString()).ToList()).Count() >= 1 || s.Split(' ').Length < min_groups || s.Split(' ').Length == 0);


            string reg = string.Empty;
            for (int i = 1; i < res.Count; i++)
            {
                res[i] = res[i].Trim();
                var r = res[i].Split(' ');
                pair[] lp = r.Where(x => x.Length > 0).Select(y => new pair(y)).ToList().ToArray();
                var qw = new List<string[]>();
                perm(lp, 0, ref qw); // standard permutations List<string>
                for (int k = 0; k < qw.Count; k++)
                {
                    string s = "";
                    var v = string.Join(" ", qw[k]).Split(' ');
                    for (int j = 0; j < v.Length; j++)
                    {
                        s += @"\d{" + v[j] + "}" + (j == v.Length - 1 ? "" : "[ -]");
                    }
                   // res[i] = s;
                    reg += '(' + s + ")" + (k == qw.Count - 1 ? "" : "|");
                }
            }
```

This works, but there has to a more computationally cheap way than the below, 
Any help appreciated.

```
(\d{7}[ -]\d{3})|(\d{3}[ -]\d{7})|(\d{6}[ -]\d{4})|(\d{4}[ -]\d{6})|(\d{5}[ -]\d{5})|(\d{5}[ -]\d{5})|(\d{4}[ -]\d{3}[ -]\d{3})(\d{4}[ -]\d{3}[ -]\d{3})(\d{3}[ -]\d{4}[ -]\d{3})(\d{3}[ -]\d{3}[ -]\d{4})(\d{3}[ -]\d{4}[ -]\d{3})(\d{3}[ -]\d{3}[ -]\d{4})
```

Comment: Are you saying no more than like for example 3 consecutive digits?

Comment: sorry no _less_ than, also must have copy pasted wrong, but you get the idea, is there no "factorized" syntax that will expand, or any combinatoric filters? Or just some godly mathamagics

Comment: You say `no less than` but your sample regex lists `\d{1}` as an option. Perhaps you should rethink / rephrase your situation.

Comment: Its completely unclear what you are actually asking for.  At least K and at most 10 digits?  All groups are at least K digits?  No groups are more than K digits?  something else?

Comment: at least m groups of _minimum_ len k (minimum consecutive \d without a [- ]),
where total amount of non [- ] characters = 10

@sln I fixed it

Comment: There is a lot of confusion about what you are asking.  It would likely be best to show examples of strings to be evaluated and the results you are expecting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you could try this

`^(?=\d(?:\D*\d){9}$)\d{1,7}(?:[ -]\d{1,7})*$`

https://regex101.com/r/t9Lnw1/1

Explained

```
 ^                             # BOS
 (?=                           # Validate the 10 digits first  
      \d 
      (?: \D* \d ){9}
      $ 
 )
                               # Then match the string based on grouping of 
 \d{1,7}                       # no more than let's say 7 for example
 (?: [ -] \d{1,7} )*
 $                             # EOS
```

Comment: aside from you using max not min, it's perfect, but if you try change it to min it causes issues,

Comment: `but if you try change it to min it causes issues,` Im afraid it causes _no issues whatsoever_. If you think I'm wrong about this, then be specific with examples. Otherwise, its perfect... If you're saying 1 digit can exist alone, but if grouped as 2 or more, it must be at least 3, you should say that ! That, of course is doable, nobody is a mindreader though.

Comment: 123 45 67890
if I want k to be 3, that means above sequence is invalid because 45 is only 2 long.
My mistake with the phrasing

Comment: Here you go 3 - 7 https://regex101.com/r/ATjjHE/1.  Please understand the example above in my answer. 1 is the minimum, 7 is the maximum = `(1,7}` It's up to you to set the min, max. For 3 to 7, it is `{3,7}`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want sequences of at least K and at most 10 digits, but you also want to ignore any single - or space that might appear between two digits.  So something like `(\d[ -]?){K,10}` should do the trick.  Obviously the `K` needs to be replaced by an actual number, and this will incidentally pick up a trailing space or - after the sequence (which you likely just want to ignore anyways.)

If you really must avoid the trailing space or -, you could use `\d([ -]?\d){K-1,9}`

If you want some more complex structure than this, your best bet may be to use a simple regex that matches a superset of your requirements, and then post-process the matches to eliminate those that don't meet the details.

Comment: `total digits are fixed`

Comment: @sin what is `K` then?  Question says "at least K and no more than 10 digits" which implies a variable number of digits in the range K to 10.

Comment: no that tests positive for 71 140 4855, if it were k=2, n = 10, but shortest grouping there is 2, total length is 9.

Comment: @Samuel a total length of 9 seems to be between 2 and 10?

Comment: I edited my question as others pointed out some issues.
'total digits are fixed, and any grouping larger than some arbitrary k (min_group_length) are allowed, with max groups being set (optional but preferred)'